# DISCONNECTION (bad value of SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME)

Tags: oracle

We start a database without sqlnet.ora file.
So as  SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME is not configured, some process has been disconnected.

We had sqlnet.ora with a SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=1, restart the listener but have still the same problem (somme disconnected process after an idle time).
It seems that the database ignore this new parameter.

We use shared server for this db (11.2).

Do you have any suggest (of course, it's impossible to restart the database)?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the settings is inside the dispatcher.
So we have shutdown the dispatchers (and of course start others) and it solve our problem